# Class export and import methods in Vue3 (Vue Cli)

Tags: vuejs3, vue-cli

I'm asking because I don't have an example.
To declare class, export, and import
What should I do?

test.js

```
export default class {
    test() {
        alert("ABC")
    }    
}
```

Main.vue

```
import exam from '../../test.js'

export default {
    setup() {      
      exam.test()
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import exam from '../../test.js'
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
    setup() {      
       const class = ref(new exam())
    } 
}
```